# Lagrangian with vanishing conjugate momentum, independent variables

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics, canonical-conjugation

Given a Lagrangian density $\mathcal L(\phi_r,\partial_\mu\phi_r,\phi_n,\partial_\mu\phi_n)$, for which we find out that for some $\phi_n$ **its conjugate momentum vanishes**:

$$\pi_n=\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial(\partial_0\phi_n)}=0.$$

1. What does this imply?
2. And if you will say that this implies that $\phi_n$ is a field depending on other fields, what does this mean?
3. Does this mean that we can construct another Lagrangian density $\hat{\mathcal L}(\phi_r,\partial_\mu\phi_r)$, which has no $\phi_n$ as its argument, so that all the fields involved are independent, but still gives a Euler-Lagrange equation having the same solution as that of ${\mathcal L}(\phi_r,\partial_\mu\phi_r,\phi_n,\partial_\mu\phi_n)$?
4. Another question, **is it true that the Hamiltonian density** $\mathcal H(\phi_r,\nabla\phi_r,\pi_r,\nabla\pi_r,\phi_n,\nabla\phi_n,\pi_n,\nabla\pi_n)$ constructed using $\mathcal L(\phi_r,\partial_\mu\phi_r,\phi_n,\partial_\mu\phi_n)$ **doesn't contain variables $\phi_n$ and $\pi_n$?**
5. Yet another question, suppose  $\mathcal H(\phi_r,\nabla\phi_r,\pi_r,\nabla\pi_r,\phi_n,\nabla\phi_n,\pi_n,\nabla\pi_n)$ does contain $\phi_n$ and $\pi_n$, but under the solution of equation of motion, $\mathcal H(\phi_r,\nabla\phi_r,\pi_r,\nabla\pi_r,\phi_n,\nabla\phi_n,\pi_n,\nabla\pi_n)=\hat{\mathcal H}(\phi_r,\nabla\phi_r,\pi_r,\nabla\pi_r)$, which $\hat{\mathcal H}$ being seen as another Hamiltonian density depents only on independent variables $\phi_r$ and $\pi_r$. Now if we derive the equation of motion of $\phi_r$ and $\pi_r$ from $\hat{\mathcal H}$, **will it be consistent with the original one** derived from $\mathcal L$, looking only at the variables $\phi_r$?

The motivation for me to consider these questions is that **only algebraic manipulations that preserve the equations of motion should make sense**, so that the symmetry examinations of $\mathcal L$ will indeed profit us finally.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59936/2451